# Problem Accessing HyperSQL from C# with JDBC

Tags: c#, .net, jdbc, hsqldb, hypersql

I'm trying to access a local HyperSQL database from a .net core 2 web application.

I have followed the instructions in the link below page to create a connector HSQLDB driver dll and referenced this in my project with no build issues and project builds and runs.
http://nikolaiklimov.de/query-java-HyperSQL-database-with-csharp/

my code throws an exception when i try to connect to the database (which i have confirmed is running on my machine) on the second line 'gettimezone'.

```
java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver());
            java.util.TimeZone.setDefault(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
            using (java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(HyperSQL))
            {

            }
```

The exception thrown is method not found in sun.util.calender.zoneinfofile

> The type initializer for 'sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile' threw an exception.
>
> Method not found: 'Void System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions)'.
>
> at Java_java_io_FileDescriptor.open(String name, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess) 
>   at java.io.FileDescriptor.open(String , Int32 , Int32 )
>   at java.io.FileDescriptor.openReadOnly(String )
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(String )
>   at java.io.FileInputStream..ctor(File file)
>   at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.1.run()
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Object , AccessControlContext , CallerID )
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction action, CallerID )
>   at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile..cctor()

Comment: `java.util.TimeZone.setDefault` looks like you are trying to set the default timezone of a JVM from your .NET app, but your .NET app doesn't use a JVM. What are you trying to accomplish with that statement?

Comment: You right i don't need that line but i added it to try to narrow down the error. If i do remove it i get the exact same exception thrown but from the line below, the 'get connection' statement.